# Angular Resource POST Request adding extra quote in JSON request

Tags: angularjs, json, post, serialization, resources

Let me start off by saying that this issue is not happening in Chrome. I have been really only testing in Chrome but then I decided to try it out in Firefox only to find I can't log in because my JSON request is not right.

Here's my call:

```
 self.user = $resource('http://my-site.com/a/account/login', {}, {
    login : {
      method: 'POST'
    },
 .
 .
 .


 self.user.login({username: username, password: password}).$promise.then(function(response) {
        self.model.loggedInUser = response;
        deferred.resolve(self.model.loggedInUser);
      }).catch(function(err) {
        self.model.loggedInUser = undefined;
        deferred.reject(err);
      });
```

I'll also mention that I have an Interceptor set up, but for this specific call all it does is the following:

```
'request' : function(config) {
      var deferred = $q.defer();
       deferred.resolve(config);
       return deferred.promise;
  }
```

So if I look in the Chrome network tab I see something like this:

```
{"username":"myName","password":"173A9F67AB4399D34561D96BFDB0E3B009C39232"}
```

Nothing out of the ordinary there.

However, this is what I see in Firefox:

```
{"username":""myName","password":"173A9F67AB4399D34561D96BFDB0E3B009C39232"}"
```

Notice the extra quotation mark after the colon and after the ending curly brace. This is not right. I can't seem to figure out what is causing this though. Espeically why it only seems to be happening in Firefox (only 2 browsers I've tried are Chrome and Firefox).

Edit: Thinking this could be useful, the Content-Type of my request is the same in both browsers:

```
application/json; charset=utf-8
```

Comment: angular transform requests quite straightforward using transformer from $http defaults - you can launch it manually and see what is the result

Comment: What do you mean I can launch it manually? I'm just confused that this seems to be working differently in different browsers.